# Play Framework DI Slick initialize

Tags: playframework, dependency-injection, slick

I'm using Play 2.4, Slick 3.0, and Play-Slick 1.0.

I'm trying to get my head around dependency injection and I've made a repo class:

```
class Articles @Inject()(protected val dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) extends Tables with HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] {

  import driver.api._

  val articles = TableQuery[ArticlesTable]
```

In a controller I can easily inject the dependency:

```
class Articles @Inject()(protected val articlesRepo: models.Articles) extends Controller {
```

How do I get an instance of Articles Repo in another class (not controller)?

Comment: Just like you did in your controller: `class WhateverClass @Inject()(protected val articlesRepo: Articles) { ...`

Comment: BTW: it is a good idea to separate the class definition from its implementation. This way you can easily change whole components of your application with just a few lines of configuration. Read more about DI in play here: https://playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ScalaDependencyInjection